# Not to change image ratio

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using free Oren template (https://wordpress.org/themes/oren/). My page: http://www.cvakni-to.cz . In home page if I click on image it will show me details about it(title, image, …). That image- i want to show it with original ratio.
Does anyone know how would i do that ?

This code I think should add that image:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'themeora-thumbnail-span-12' ); ?>
```

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to utilize the full image size:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );          // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
```

This will load the actual image that you uploaded to the media library.

Comment: Thanks for comment, actually my customer is photographer and uploaded pictures are very big. I would like to have cropped image but in original ratio.

Or at least somehow get width and height of that original uploaded image.